# How to delete an object ( node ) which is in use

Tags: c++

I have the following code that inserts item to a double-linked list using iterator. This is how we are asked to do it. The code works, but the problem is that I have absolute memory leak of 24 bytes.

```
NodeIterator<T> insert(NodeIterator<T> & itrPassed, const T datapassed)
{
    Node<T> * newNode = new Node<T>(datapassed);
    Node<T>* previousOfCurrent = itrPassed.getCurrent()->previous;
    previousOfCurrent-> next = newNode;
    newNode -> previous = previousOfCurrent;
    newNode -> next = itrPassed.getCurrent();
    itrPassed.setCurrent(newNode);
    return itrPassed;
}
```

I know that the problem is caused by this line `Node<T> * newNode = new Node<T>(datapassed);`. I can't delete the newNode object as I am returning an iterator pointing to it and it is used in my linked list.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: You are right to think that you shouldn't delete the newNode object here. It should be deleted when the list goes out of scope--in the destructor. Also as a sidenote, this looks dangerous. What happens if the iterator they pass is to the first node in your list?

Comment: What about using `std::unique_ptr<Node>` for the `previous` and `next` members of `Node<T>` and don't worry about the memory management details?

Comment: Why do you want to delete it? It is in your linked list. The problem I think is that while you update the node preceeding the inserted one, you do not update the one that follows it. Your double-linked list becomes broken and who knows what happens next because of it?

Comment: @scohe001 Thanks, I forgot about that situation. I will have an if statement for it and do the changes required. Regarding the destructor, do I need to delete newNode there ?

Comment: @user0042 our lecturer told us not to have memory leaks otherwise we will lose marks. I will try the unique_ptr idea

Comment: @samPRE you need to delete ALL the nodes there. And any other dynamic memory the list may have allocated in its lifecycle

Comment: @CygnusX1 I think I am updating the next and previous of the inserted node

Comment: @scohe001 I have the following for the destructor  `~LinkedList()
 {

  Node<T>* current = head;

  while (current!=nullptr)
  {
   Node<T>* nextNode = current->next;
   delete current;
   current = nextNode;

  }

 }` Is it correct ?

Comment: @samPRE Yes, you are updating the inserted node and its predecessor, but *not* its successor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem I see is that you are not updating the `previous` of the current node. The `previous` of the current node still points to the old node. As a consequence, if you are iterating over the nodes using `previous`, you are going to skip over the newly created node.

The other problem I see is that you are accessing `previousOfCurrent` without checking whether it is a valid pointer.

Not sure whether fixing them will fix your memory leak problem.

```
NodeIterator<T> insert(NodeIterator<T> & itrPassed, const T datapassed)
{
    Node<T> * newNode = new Node<T>(datapassed);
    Node<T>* previousOfCurrent = itrPassed.getCurrent()->previous;

    // Prevent accessing a nullptr
    if ( previousOfCurrent != nullptr )
    {
       previousOfCurrent-> next = newNode;
       newNode -> previous = previousOfCurrent;
    }

    newNode -> next = itrPassed.getCurrent();

    // Add this
    itrPassed.getCurrent()->previous = newNode;

    itrPassed.setCurrent(newNode);
    return itrPassed;
}
```

Comment: @samPRE, updated the answer by adding the `nullptr` check.

Comment: This sorted it out. Thanks so much

Comment: what I added is `previousOfCurrent = newNode` which is the same idea that u gave

Comment: @samPRE, that does not sound right, even if it appears to have resolved your problem.

Comment: how come ? It is the same thing as what u asked me to do in the ( // Add this )

Comment: @samPRE, please post the updated version of your function by appending it to your post. That would give me a better idea of whether what you have is correct or not.

Comment: It turned out that I was using valgrind on the wrong file lool, The memory leak is still there. I copied the code u have typed and pasted it there and I am still getting memory leak. I will ask my lecturer and I will see. Thanks for reminding me of the `itrPassed.getCurrent()->previous = newNode;`

Comment: I asked the lecturer and it turned out that this function is working fine, I had another function called erase which caused the memory leak.

Comment: @samPRE, that's just another reason why keep harping on people to post a [mcve]. It's much easier to see all the problems with that. Seems like your program is working now. Good for you. Happy programming.